# Read 3 output lines into 3 variables in bash

Tags: linux, bash

I have a command that generates 3 lines of output such as

```
$ ./mycommand
1
asdf
qwer zxcv
```

I'd like to assign those 3 lines to 3 different variables ($a, $b, $c) such that

```
$ echo $a
1
$ echo $b
asdf
$ echo $c
qwer zxcv
```

I'm familiar with the while loop method that would normally be used for reading 3 lines at a time from output that contains sets of 3 lines. But that seems less than elegant considering my command will only ever output 3 lines.

I tried playing around with various combinations of values for `IFS=` and options for `read -r a b c`, sending the command output as stdin, but I could only ever get it to set the first line to the first variable. Some examples:

```
IFS= read -r a b c < <(./mycommand)
IFS=$'\n' read -r a b c < <(./mycommand)
IFS= read -r -d $'\n' < <(./mycommand)
```

If I modify my command so that the 3 lines are separated by spaces instead of newlines, I can successfully just use this variation as long as each former line is properly quoted:

```
read -r a b c < <(./mycommand)
```

And while that is working for the purposes of my current project, it's still bugging me that I couldn't get it to work the other way.  So I'm wondering if anyone can see and explain what I was missing in my original attempt with the 3 lines of output.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you want to read data from three lines, use three reads:

```
{ read -r a; read -r b; read -r c; } < <(./mycommand)
```

`read` reads a chunk of data and then splits it up. You couldn't get it to work because your chunks were always single lines.

Comment: Aww man! I even tried 3 separate reads at one point, but didn't know to enclose them in curly braces.  Thank you so much.  Answer will be accepted as soon as the timeout is up.

Comment: Why didn't it work when he set `IFS=$'\n'`? Shouldn't that have treated all the input as one line, and split it at the newlines?

Comment: @Barmar Because the read itself stops at the first `\n`. It needs to be told to read all the input with `-d ''` (a null), and IFS set: `IFS=$'\n'`. This line works: `IFS=$'\n' read -d '' a b c < <(mycommand)`. However, `readarray -t arr < <(mycommand)` is simpler (more idiomatic).

Comment: @BinaryZebra It only works if the input has no nulls.

Comment: @thatotherguy But Of Course!! It is **not possible** to store a null (character octall 000) inside a variable. A `read -d ''` will use the null as the delimiter and stop reading on the first null (as is expected because -d sets the delimiter). But even if the null were read, the variable will not store the null. The command readarray -t deals in a similar way with nulls. Please read [my edited answer for the details](http://stackoverflow.com/a/33049566/2350426).

Comment: @thatotherguy And, honestly, your solution also fails with nulls. Try: `mycommand(){ echo -e "one\nas\000df\n*\nqwer zxcv"; }; { read -r a; read -r b; read -r c; } < <(mycommand)`. That will set (incorrectly) `b=as`, missing the null and the df. But that is as it should be expected, it is a trait of the shell.

Comment: Works perfectly for me when Line2 is empty. Thanks :)

Answer (score 3):

Newer BASH versions support `mapfile` command. Using that you can read all the lines into an array:

```
mapfile -t ary < <(./command)
```

Check the array content:

```
declare -p ary
declare -a ary='([0]="1" [1]="asdf" [2]="qwer zxcv")'
```

Comment: I probably would've have gone this route originally if I couldn't change the output of my command.  Good to know though.

Comment: You don't need to change output of your command to use `mapfile` and since it is using afraid it is dynamic also. It will work with 4,5_6 lines of output as well.

Comment: There is a problem when line 2 is empty. Bash arrays interpret a null string as a deleted entry so line 3 goes into second array index. A simple solution of $Line1="blah blah", $Line2="" and $Line3="BLAH BLAH" does not work with your answer.

Comment: That's not correct. `mapfile` does read empty lines also in array. Try this command: `mapfile -t ary < <(printf '%s\n\n%s\n' 'Line1' 'Line2'); declare -p ary`

Answer (score 3):

Perhaps this explanation will be useful to you.

> ... it's still bugging me that I couldn't get it to work the other way. So I'm wondering if anyone can see and explain what I was missing in my original attempt with the 3 lines of output.

Simple: `read` works only with one line (by default). This:

```
#!/bin/bash

mycommand(){ echo -e "1\nasdf\nqwer zxcv"; }

read a b c < <(mycommand)

printf 'first  : %s\nsecond : %s\nthird  : %s\n' "$a" "$b" "$c"
```

Will print:

```
first  : 1
second : 
third  :
```

However, using a **null** character will capture the whole string in (replace this line above):

```
    read -d '' a b c < <(mycommand)
```

Will print:

```
first  : 1
second : asdf
third  : qwer zxcv
```

The `read` command absorbed the whole output of the command and was broken into parts with the default value of IFS: <kbd>Space</kbd><kbd>Tab</kbd><kbd>Enter</kbd>.

In this specific example, that worked correctly because the last value is the one with more than one "part".
But this kind of processing is very brittle. For example: this other possible output of the command, the assignment to variables will break:

```
mycommand(){ echo -e "1 and 2\nasdf and dfgh\nqwer zxcv"; }
```

Will output (incorrectly):

```
first  : 1
second : and
third  : 2
asdf and dfgh
qwer zxcv
```

The processing is brittle. To make it robust we need to use a loop. But you say that that is something you already know:

```
#!/bin/bash
mycommand(){ echo -e "1 and 2\nasdf and dfgh\nqwer zxcv"; }

i=0; while read arr[i]; do ((i++)); done < <(mycommand)

printf 'first  : %s\nsecond : %s\nthird  : %s\n' "${arr[0]}" "${arr[1]}" "${arr[2]}"
```

Which will (correctly) print:

```
first  : 1 and 2
second : asdf and dfgh
third  : qwer zxcv
```

However, the loop could be made simpler using bash command readarray:

```
#!/bin/bash

mycommand(){ echo -e "1 and 2\nasdf and dfgh\nqwer zxcv"; }

readarray -t arr < <(mycommand)

printf 'first  : %s\nsecond : %s\nthird  : %s\n' "${arr[0]}" "${arr[1]}" "${arr[2]}"
```

And using a printf "loop" will make the structure work for any count of input lines:

```
#!/bin/bash
mycommand(){ echo -e "1 and 2\nasdf and dfgh\n*\nqwer zxcv"; }

readarray -t arr < <(mycommand)
printf 'value : %s\n' "${arr[@]}"
```

Hope that this helped.

**EDIT**

#### About nulls (in simple read):

In bash, the use of nulls is almost never practical. In specific, nulls are erased silently in most condidions. This solution does suffer of that limitation.

Including a null in the input:

```
mycommand(){ echo -e "1 and 2\nasdf and dfgh\n\000\n*\nqwer zxcv"; }
```

will make a simple `read -r -d ''` get the input up to the first null (understanding such null as the character with octal 000).

```
echo "test one:"; echo
echo "input"; echo
mycommand | od -tcx1

echo "output"; echo
read -r -d '' arr < <(mycommand)
echo "$arr" | od -tcx1
```

Gives this as output:

```
test one:

input

0000000   1       a   n   d       2  \n   a   s   d   f       a   n   d
         31  20  61  6e  64  20  32  0a  61  73  64  66  20  61  6e  64
0000020       d   f   g   h  \n  \0  \n   *  \n   q   w   e   r       z
         20  64  66  67  68  0a  00  0a  2a  0a  71  77  65  72  20  7a
0000040   x   c   v  \n
         78  63  76  0a
0000044

output

0000000   1       a   n   d       2  \n   a   s   d   f       a   n   d
         31  20  61  6e  64  20  32  0a  61  73  64  66  20  61  6e  64
0000020       d   f   g   h  \n
         20  64  66  67  68  0a
0000026
```

It is clear that the value captured by read stops at the first octal 000.
Which, frankly, is to be expected.

---

#### About nulls (in readarray):

I have to report, however, that readarray does **not** stop at the octal 000 but just silently removes it (an usual shell trait).
Running this code:

```
#!/bin/bash
mycommand(){ echo -e "1 and 2\nasdf and dfgh\n\000\n*\nqwer zxcv"; }
echo "test two:"; echo
echo "input"; echo
mycommand | od -tcx1

echo "output"; echo
readarray -t arr < <(mycommand)
printf 'value : %s\n' "${arr[@]}"
echo
printf 'value : %s\n' "${arr[@]}"|od -tcx1
```

Renders this output:

```
test two:

input

0000000   1       a   n   d       2  \n   a   s   d   f       a   n   d
         31  20  61  6e  64  20  32  0a  61  73  64  66  20  61  6e  64
0000020       d   f   g   h  \n  \0  \n   *  \n   q   w   e   r       z
         20  64  66  67  68  0a  00  0a  2a  0a  71  77  65  72  20  7a
0000040   x   c   v  \n
         78  63  76  0a
0000044

output

value : 1 and 2
value : asdf and dfgh
value : 
value : *
value : qwer zxcv

0000000   v   a   l   u   e       :       1       a   n   d       2  \n
         76  61  6c  75  65  20  3a  20  31  20  61  6e  64  20  32  0a
0000020   v   a   l   u   e       :       a   s   d   f       a   n   d
         76  61  6c  75  65  20  3a  20  61  73  64  66  20  61  6e  64
0000040       d   f   g   h  \n   v   a   l   u   e       :      \n   v
         20  64  66  67  68  0a  76  61  6c  75  65  20  3a  20  0a  76
0000060   a   l   u   e       :       *  \n   v   a   l   u   e       :
         61  6c  75  65  20  3a  20  2a  0a  76  61  6c  75  65  20  3a
0000100       q   w   e   r       z   x   c   v  \n
         20  71  77  65  72  20  7a  78  63  76  0a
0000113
```

That is, the null 000 or just \0 gets silently removed.

Comment: This is great info that I'm sure I will be referencing many times. Thanks for the detail.